# $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. If $E(X) = E(Y)\;$ and $P(X \geq Y) =1\;$ then $X = Y$ almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory

I came across the statment that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. If $E(X) = E(Y)\;$ and $P(X \geq Y) =1\;$ then $X = Y$ almost surely.

I know that it is sufficient to show that $P(Y \geq X) =1\;$, I tried by using the linearity of the expectation. I know that:

$E(X) - E(Y) = E(X-Y) = \sum _{\omega \in \Omega} (X-Y)(\omega)P(\left \{ \omega \right \}) = 0$

However, I don't really know how to proceed from here.

I'd love to get some help!

Comment: If $Z=X-Y$ then $EZ =0$ and $Z \geq 0$ a.s. This implies $Z=0$ a.s..

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry if this is too elementary, but do you mind demonstrating why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to argue by contradiction.

If $X$ isn't equal to $Y$ almost surely, then there is a positive probability that $X \neq Y$, say $\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \geq \delta > 0$. Now, together with the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq Y) =1$ it follows that $\mathbb{P}(X > Y) \geq \delta$.

Now, if as indicated in your question we're working in a finite probability space this is already sufficient to find a contradiction, since $\min \{ X(\omega) - Y(\omega) \colon X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)\} = \alpha$ exists and then it's not hard to show that $\mathbb{E}(X) > \mathbb{E}(Y) + \delta \alpha$.

Otherwise one has to be a bit more careful and consider the events
$$
A_n = \{ \omega \colon \frac{1}{n-1} > X(\omega) - Y(\omega) > \frac{1}{n}\} 
$$
We know that $\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup A_n) \right) > \delta$ and so there must be some $m$ and $\epsilon$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_m) > \epsilon$, and then we can argue as before.